# Join two tables and create indexed array where each row is a category containing multiple data,

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Table: policy

| id | title | description | open_flg (defines published status) | open_date (defines publishing date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | policy title1 | desc example | 1 | 2022/02/22 |
| 2 | policy title2 | desc example | 1 | 2022/02/23 |

Table: policy_case

| id | policy_id | title | contents | open_flg | open_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | example | example | 1 | 2022/02/22 |
| 2 | 2 | example | example | 1 | 2022/02/23 |
| 3 | 2 | example | example | 1 | 2022/02/23 |

I want to make a table where 'policy' is the parent and policy_case is the child. `policy.id` is the same as `policy_case.policy_id` It should be something like this:

| id | title | description | case_title | case_contents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | policy title1 | desc example | example | example |
| 1 | policy title1 | desc example | example | example |
| 2 | policy title2 | desc example | example | example |

I've used the following code:

```
$this->db->select('policy.id,policy.title,policy.description,case.policy_id,case.id as case_id,case.title as case_title,case.contents as case_contents');
      $this->db->from('policy');
      $this->db->join('policy_case case', 'case.policy_id = policy.id');
      $join = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
      
      $query = $this->db->query($join);
  $data['policies'] = $query->result_array();
```

The only problem I have is that `policy.description` and `policy.title` will also get duplicates depending on the number of cases. If I try to use `foreach` to output the array data it will create 3 policy titles, instead of 2.

Here's my current page HTML (I haven't figured a way to loop the cases inside policy):

```
<?php foreach ($policies as $key => $val) { ?>
<h2><?php echo $val['title']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $val['description']; ?></p>
<h3><?php echo $val['case_title']; ?></h3>
<p><?php echo $val['case_contents']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure the result so that `cases` is an array within each policy, but it is an unnecessary step which would offer no benefit.

When iterating over your result set, you need to keep track of the previous policy, so you can decide whether to print the `<h2>`, or not:

```php
<?php

$prev_policy_id = null;

foreach ($policies as $policy) {

    if ($policy->policy_id != $prev_policy_id) {
        echo "<h2>{$policy->title}</h2>";
        echo "<p>{$policy->description}</p>";
    }

    echo "<h3>{$policy->case_title}</h3>";
    echo "<p>{$policy->case_contents}</p>";

    $prev_policy_id = $policy->policy_id;
}
?>
```

This is dependent on the result set being ordered by policy, so all cases in the same policy are together:

```php
$data['policies'] = $this->db->select('case.policy_id, policy.title, policy.description, case.id as case_id, case.title as case_title, case.contents as case_contents')
    ->from('policy');
    ->join('policy_case case', 'case.policy_id = policy.id')
    ->order_by('policy.id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Obviously, you can continue using `result_array()` (just add it after `->get()`), I just dropped it as I find the object notation easier to read.